# How to get a customcontroller to return only certain data in a query?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, query, custom-controller

So i want to create a custom page, that shows only won opportunities, that is supposedly not possible with a standard controller, hence I tried my luck building a custom controller. It has failed thus far, so i came here for wisdom.
My code looks like this, I have unsuccessfully tried to make the controller only return closed/won Opportunities. These futile attempts, i´ve not listed here.
The controllercode is more or less standard...

```
public with sharing class gewonneneKunden 
{
    private final Opportunity opp;
 public gewonneneKunden(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) 
 {
    this.opp = (Opportunity)controller.getRecord();
 }
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController opportunityRecords 
    {
    get 
        {
        if(opportunityRecords == null) 
        {
            opportunityRecords = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([
                SELECT Name, Telefon__c, E_Mail__c, Amount, Geplanter_Starttermin__c, Name_opp__c 
                FROM Opportunity
                Where IsWon = TRUE]));
        }
        return OpportunityRecords;
        }
    private set;
    }
public List<Opportunity> getgewonneKunden() 
{
     return (List<Opportunity>) opportunityRecords.getRecords();
}
```

}

Is there a kind soul, that can help me? It would be most appreciated

**UPDATE 1. Testing:**

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=TRUE) //was considering just using Sandbox data, 
public with sharing class ControllerTest 
{
public static testmethod void gkcTest()
{
    PageReference pageRef = Page.Bestandskunden;
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

    Opportunity o = (Opportunity) Json.deserialize('{"name":"John Doe", 
"isWon": true}',
                                            Opportunity.class);

      // Instantiating the controller with all parameters?!?!? calling my 
methods as you say?     

    gewonneneKundenController = new gewonnneneKundenController();
    Controller.getData();
    List<Opportunity> opps = controller.getOpportunities();
    System.assertEquals(opps.size(1));
    gewonneneKunden.returnRecord();
    List<Opportunity> opps = [select Name, Telefon__c, E_Mail__c, Amount, Geplanter_Starttermin__c, Name_opp__c from Opportunity where IsWon=TRUE]; 

}    
}
```

I have tried to somehow reconstruct my controller, but got stuck doing so, i hope i am somewhat on the right track, i am stuck at 74% code clearance which is ironic as well as frustrating, if you could find the time to help me once more that would be terrific, thank you for all your guidance thus far. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really just missing a WHERE clause:

```
        setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(
            Database.getQueryLocator([
                SELECT Name, Telefon__c, E_Mail__c, Amount 
                FROM Opportunity
                WHERE IsWon = TRUE]));
```

---

Based on your edit, your class' code should be modified slightly:

```
public with sharing class gewonneneKunden {
    ApexPages.StandardSetController opportunityRecords;
    public gewonneneKunden(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
                opportunityRecords = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([
                    SELECT Name, Telefon__c, E_Mail__c, Amount, Geplanter_Starttermin__c, Name_opp__c 
                    FROM Opportunity
                    Where IsWon = TRUE]));
     }
    public List<Opportunity> getgewonneKunden() 
    {
         return (List<Opportunity>) opportunityRecords.getRecords();
    }
}
```

From there, your unit test is also close, but should be modified:

```
@isTest class ControllerTest 
{
    public static testmethod void gkcTest() {
    PageReference pageRef = Page.Bestandskunden;
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
    // Create test data
    Account a = new Account(Name='Test');
    insert a;
    Opportunity o = new Opportunity(AccountId=a.Id, Name='Test', CloseDate=Date.today(), StageName='Closed Won', Amount=0.00);
    insert o;

    Test.startTest();
    // null here is the first parameter; we are not using it,
    // but we need it in order to use the page as a list button.
    gewonneneKunden controller = new gewonnneneKunden(null);
    // Expected value 1 should come first
    System.assertEquals(1, controller.getgewonneKunden().size());
}    
}
```

Comment: I have written the line just as you said, and most seems to be working well, but the FROM is declared an unexpected token, which is confusing to me. Do you have a suggestion? :) and thank you very much for helping me already

Comment: @Luke Possibly a stray comma or something? Try reading up on [SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm).

Comment: could you help me, how i would go about testing that code? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Luke you might want to search the forums here, but generally speaking, you will create data, create your controller, then call your methods. In your case, create a new Opportunity, then construct your controller, then call the methods. If you get stuck, do feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: i have edited the post and wrote down my test code, that i have. Thank you for bearing with me. If you´d have some more insight for me that would be appreciated very much.

Comment: @Luke Looks like you over-generalized your original question. It's okay, I've went ahead and edited my answer to match.

Comment: Thank you for the time you´ve invested, i´ve managed to test the code as 100% ;) the controller doesn´t accept the Where clause though, it did through the entirety of the week, but now just doesn´t anymore ...

Comment: @Luke What do you mean, it doesn't accept the where clause?

Comment: well, it does not filter accordingly, it just shows a selection of 20 random opportunities. I have been suspecting, that that is due to my production orga beeing german and the API beeing german, but even using the german api name did not solve it

Comment: @Luke Field names don't change (e.g. IsWon), so it should be working. Have you tried your query directly using the Developer Console to see what you get back?

Comment: I did and there it works perfectly and i only get back what i need i.e. won opportunities.

Comment: I have added this line !!           
               controller.setPageSize(controller.getResultSize());                 it  solves the problem of limited amount of  opportunities but now there is a  system.nullpointerexception error